# how can I allocate jvm to Talend?

Tags: windows, jvm, talend, jvm-arguments

I have 16 gb windows system and I want to allocate 12gb to Talend.

Is there anyone who knows this.

What parameters are needed to change in Talend's configuration `.ini` file?

Comment: See this link : https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Allocating+more+memory+to+Talend+Studio

Answer (score 0):

If `talend` (whatever that is) is a jvm process, then you should add `-Xmx12G` and `-Xms12G`. Now the question is: what is that thing doing (is that a toolkit?) that it needs `12GB` of memory?